# Embedded Google Document Viewer (PDF): How to scroll horizontal

Tags: html, pdf, embed, google-document-viewer

i've embedded google doc viewer api to show a pdf on a website:

```
    <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
        <iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf&embedded=true" align="middle" style="width:90%; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
```

I did look for some kind of documentation to see all available parameters for the passed url. However I did not find any.
Basically i want to make the Google PDF Viewer to scroll horizontally instead of vertically. (expecting somth. like "&scroll=horizontally").
Can anyone help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Afaik this is not possible.
You can download the PDF and use any libary to handle the PDF from your Server so you don't need to use iframe.

Comment: I dont want to care about mobile divces / different / old browers support etc. Thats why i'd like to use googles doc viewer api

Comment: Then use googles doc viewer api, but it is not possible to scroll horizontally instead of vertically.